# Using an attribute on a component registered in a palette results in AV

Tags: attributes, components, using

Appears when re-installing the package. If you use the base TCustomAttribute - does not appear, only when using any heir. Under Win10 does not appear, only under Win7.

```
unit Test.ComponentWithAttribute.Register;
interface
uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TUseAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  end;

  [TUseAttribute]
  TComponentWithAttribute = class(TComponent)
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('ComponentWithAttribute', [TComponentWithAttribute]);
end;

end.
```

[Fatal Error] Access violation at address 5005F8E8 in module 'rtl260.bpl'. Read of address 2C031FD0

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Whether this behavior is expected or not, is there a solution to the problem. I need components with attributes registered in the palette.